# Adjust contrast and brighness of icons in Windows 7

Tags: windows-explorer, images, icons

Is there a way to preview multiple very low brightness TIFF images without opening them?

These 16-bit images look dark because of the contrast and brightness setting of Windows Explorer.  I have hundreds of images so I'd like to take a quick look at all of them simultaneously.

Can I adjust the Windows Explorer icons contrast and brightness?

[image]

Comment: Could you show a picture of how the tiff files look in a viewer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. They are black and white pictures.  I would prefer not posting them because they are proprietary information.